# Can `filename` strings be sent to R via Rserve with PHP?

Tags: php, r, lamp, rserve

I'm using R (http://www.r-project.org/) on a LAMP system with Rserve-php (https://code.google.com/p/rserve-php/). I would like to send a .csv file to R. Is this possible?

I tried using evalString(), but it did not work and returned the error below. The connection to R and the required files are okay. The output returns `Hello World!` as expected.

evalString() from rcodetest.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'rconfig.php';
require 'rConnection.php';
//$test_cases = Rserve_Tests_Definition::$native_tests;
try {
    echo '<p>Connecting to Rserve '.RSERVE_HOST;
    $r = new Rserve_Connection(RSERVE_HOST);
    echo ' OK</p>';
    $result = $r->evalString('x ="Hello World!"; x');
    echo $result;
    $filex = $r->evalString("filename=('folder\\folder\\folder\\file.csv')");
    $r->close();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
?>
```

Error:

`exception 'Rserve_Exception' with message 'Unexpected packet Data type (expect     DT_SEXP)' in /path/rConnection.php:201 Stack trace: #0 /path/rConnection.php(237):     Rserve_Connection->parseResponse(NULL, 0) #1 /path/rcodetest.php(14): Rserve_Connection-    >evalString('filename=('fold...') #2 {main}`

Answer (score 0):

Try using read.table.  This is if you are trying to process the .csv file.

```
$filex = $r->evalString("read.table('folder/folder/folder/file.csv', sep = ',')");



<?php
require_once 'rconfig.php';
require 'rConnection.php';
//$test_cases = Rserve_Tests_Definition::$native_tests;
try {
    echo '<p>Connecting to Rserve '.RSERVE_HOST;
    $r = new Rserve_Connection(RSERVE_HOST);
    echo ' OK</p>';
    $result = $r->evalString('x ="Hello World!"; x');
    echo $result;
    $filex = $r->evalString("read.table('folder/folder/folder/file.csv', sep = ',')");
    $r->close();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
?>
```

Using

```
filename=('folder/folder/folder/file.csv')
```

... is only assigning the string value to filename.

```
> filename=("~/config.yml")
> filename
[1] "~/config.yml"
> typeof(filename)
[1] "character"
```

Also, the preferred assignment operator in R is `<-`.

Comment: Tried `read.table`. Unfortunately, it still returns the same error.

Comment: That solved the "Unexpected Packet Data Type" error. Now it's just "unable to evaluate". `exception 'Rserve_Exception' with message 'unable to evaluate' in /folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/rConnection.php:239 Stack trace: #0 /folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/rcodetest.php(13): Rserve_Connection->evalString('read.table('fol...') #1 {main}`

Comment: Are you able to execute: `"x = read.table('folder/folder/folder/file.csv', sep = ',')"`

Comment: What are the results of `$filex = $r->evalString("file('folder/folder/folder/file.csv')")`

Comment: Returns the "unable to evaluate" error. With the trouble it's currently having with a .csv, is there a way that I can just read the table in from MySql?